# Import export of MongoDb database from local instance to Mongo Atlas

Tags: mongodb, backup

I want to import a DB into the Mongo Atlas from my managed mongo instance(which is managed by us).
The backup is in the form of BSON.

Want some hints, how can I do that.

MongoDB - 6.0

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

Found the steps:

1. Take the backup of existing DB.

   **mongodump --host [IP ADDRESS] --port [PORT] --db [DB NAME] --authenticationDatabase [DB NAME] --username [USERNAME] --password [PASSWORD] --out [BACKUP DIRECTORY]**
2. Once the backup is ready, copy it to Atlas using this.

   **mongorestore --uri "[MONGO ATLAS CLUSTER URL]" --db=[DB NAME] [BACKUP DIRECTORY]**

The right access needs to be given to user.

Thanks,
Atul